# Why won't my kitchen sink drain? Disposal is working but when I run it water backs up into single sink

Tags: sink, disposal

When I run my kitchen sink disposal, it sounded odd earlier today (after I put watermelon rind down it, idiot I guess), but tonight when I ran it, the disposal seems to work fine but the water will not drain. When the disposal is running, it seems to suck the water down into it, but when I turn it off, the water shoots back into the sink.

I unscrewed the P trap, and all looks fine. 
I have a 30" drain snake, which I snaked into the pipe that goes into the wall. It came back with black greasy film but nothing else obvious.

Now that I put the P trap back together, the same thing is happening in the sink. Disposal runs but water does not drain and gets kicked back into sink when I turn off the disposal.

Answer (score 2):

There is (obviously) a blockage.  First off, watermelon rind should not be placed in a disposer, it's too tough and fibrous and often clogs up the drains.

If you took apart the P trap and found nothing, it's either blocked before or after the trap.  Most likely before, at the outlet of the disposer.

Take all the pipes apart and find the blockage.  If there is nothing there, then it's in the drain past the part that can be seen below the sink and you need either better tools, like a longer snake or you need to get a plumber in who can clear it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The blockage is likely in the lower chamber of the disposer or the disposer downspout.
Remove the drainpipe at the disposer.  Look through the opening and see if grind up food and grease has formed a 'paste' on the inter-wall or clogging the chamber. Fibrous vegetables can also form large gobs of waste matter similar to hair balls after passing through the grinder.  This waste in the lower chamber is impossible to flush out. 
Unplug the disposer. Use a probe, drain brush, or other items to scrape the rotten mess out of the chamber.

Reconnect the drain pipe, and flush with hot water for several minutes.